# Word guessing game, what algorithm to use?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, puzzle

I have a list of number `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and now i make some combination out of them. Let's say `[2,2,4,5,1,1]`.

Now the program has to guess what combinations did I think.
Then the program will generate a random list with the same length as was my combination. Let's say, it will be `[1,2,5,5,4,3]`.

Now I have to tell how many numbers where at the correct location and how many numbers where correct but at the wrong place. So, at the correct are two numbers in this case (2 and 5). Also 1 and 3 where correct but at the wrong place.

Initially, the program should guess the password using my hints. Can someone please help me figure out or give hints to an algorithm that is used to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: There's a game with exactly these rules: Mastermind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29). The article also provides several approaches to solve the game.

Comment: Yes, in mastermind, if you get the right color in the right place, it tells you exactly where it is. So you know which one is the correct one. My problem is a bit more complicated because i only know how many are correct but i have no clue which one or on what position. But thank you for your answer. Didn't know nothing of that game before.

Comment: No it is exactly what I need.

Comment: "it tells you exactly where it is" - nope.

Answer (score 1):

"Then the program will generate a random list with the same length as was my combination" - is this part of the problem?  You say later that the program uses your hints, so I assume you are generating random lists of numbers to try and trying to figure out the password while using only random lists of numbers and not using the information you have to make better guesses that can narrow down the results more quickly.

In that case, you need to keep track of your guesses and for each one figure out what information you can glean from them.  Each time you get new information from a guess, you can go back to the results of your previous guesses and see if you get any new information.  For your example, let's say it goes like this including my made up guesses after the first:

```
PASSWORD: [2,2,4,5,1,1]
GUESS 1:  [1,2,5,5,4,3] - 4 correct, 2 right position
GUESS 2:  [5,2,1,7,3,8] - 3 correct, 1 right position
GUESS 3:  [7,7,8,3,7,9] - 0 correct, 0 right position
GUESS 4:  [5,6,5,3,8,9] - 1 correct, 0 right position
GUESS 5:  [8,2,5,6,7,3] - 2 correct, 1 right position
```

After guess 3 you know that you have no 3s, 7s, 8s or 9s.  Going back to your second guess, you know that three of the numbers are 1,2,5 because you have no 3,7,8.  Going back to your first guess with that knowledge you know that the answer has 1,2,5 as well as either a 4 or 5.  Looking at the 4th guess you now know there is only one 5, so four of your numbers are 1,2,4,5.  Continue with this algorithm until you figure out all 6 numbers, not caring what position they are in.

Once you have all 6 numbers, you switch algorithms to figure out what positions the numbers are in.  Go back through all your previous guesses each time you learn new information and continue guessing random passwords if you are stuck.  For the initial run, you know that 5 is not in positions one or three because of guess 4.  Guess 2 - you know the 5 isn't in position 1, so either the 2 or the 1 is in the right position [X,2,1,X,X,X].  Guess 1 you know that the 5 isn't in position 3, so 2 of the following are in the right position: [1,2,X,5,4,X].  Guess 5 tells you that either the 2 or the 5 is in the right position, but you know the 5 is in the wrong position because of Guess 4, so now you know the 2 is in position 2.  Combining this information with guess 2 tells you that the 1 is not in position 3 either, so you know it has to be 4 or 2.

One way to represent your knowledge would be having arrays for min and max counts for each digit and an array of boolean for each spot telling you what numbers can go there.  Once you have all the information you can get from a guess, you can remove it from the list so you don't have to look at it again.  So after Guess 3, the max number of 3,7,8,9 are 0.  You can also set those possibilities to false for each position.  That is all the information you can get so you no longer have to look at Guess 3.

You can also alter the guesses to simplify it, for instance once you know that 2 goes in position 2 and that there are no 3,7,8, you can remove those "knowns" and Guess 2 changes:

```
GUESS 2:  [5,2,1,7,3,8] - 3 correct, 1 right position
NEW   2:  [5,X,1,X,X,X] - 2 correct, 0 right position
```

But once you know all the numbers and have set 5 to false for position 1 and 1 to false for position 3, this can't give you more information and you can remove this guess from your list.

Answer (score 0):

Well this should help you make a start on it. The below code will help generate your random combination consisting of numbers from 1 to 10

```
from random import randrange

# randrange will generate a random number between 1 and 11
# the end value 11 is not included

# for _ in range(0, 6) is used to iterate 6 times
comb = [randrange(1, 11) for _ in range(0, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer:* This solution won't work with your problem set size, as yours is 10^6, and the algorithm is quadratic. The quadratic part is the one that's easy to fix (if you don't care about optimal solutions), you don't have to consider all the possible guesses, it's enough to do sampling and test whether a sample is good enough (e.g.: at least halves the state-space). The one thing that's lot harder to fix is the initial size of the state-space. You could hardcode some initial guesses (e.g. hardcoding the first 3 guesses), then generate the initial state-space only with valid combinations (e.g.: if you figure out that there's no '1' on the board, then don't generate guesses that contain '1').

---

Here's a code that uses [Knuth's minmax solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29#Five-guess_algorithm) to the problem.

- We maintain a set of guesses that can be solutions based on the previous guesses.
- We consider each of them as the next move, and calculate the worst case scenario, that is, the largest possible size of the set after the guess.
- From these worst case scenarios we pick the best, that is, the next move that's guaranteed to reduce the size of the set the most.
- We play this guess and based on the answer we elliminate the impossible solutions from the set.
- We do this until we find the solution.

I made a small modification (mainly for code simplicity and speed) so that only valid answers are considered for the next guess. Because of that, the algorithm sometimes needs extra step(s).

> Knuth also gives an example showing that in some cases no member of S
>   will be among the highest scoring guesses and thus the guess cannot
>   win on the next turn, yet will be necessary to assure a win in five.

Here's such a pathological example:

```
Secret: [1, 1, 1, 0]
(0, 0, 1, 1) -> (1, 2)
(5, 1, 1, 0) -> (3, 0)
(4, 1, 1, 0) -> (3, 0)
(3, 1, 1, 0) -> (3, 0)
(2, 1, 1, 0) -> (3, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 0) -> (4, 0)
Done in 6 steps
```

It could have easily figured out the missing color in less steps, but because it tries only valid solutions, it needed an extra step.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
import itertools
import collections

COLORS, PEGS = 6, 4

def random_secret():
    return [random.randrange(COLORS) for _ in range(PEGS)]

def all_states():
    return list(itertools.product(*[range(COLORS) for _ in range(PEGS)]))

def evaluate(secret, guess):
    color_and_pos = 0
    color = 0
    colors = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(len(secret)):
        if secret[i] == guess[i]:
            color_and_pos += 1
        else:
            colors[secret[i]] += 1
    for i in range(len(secret)):
        if secret[i] != guess[i]:
            if colors[guess[i]] > 0:
                colors[guess[i]] -= 1
                color += 1
    return (color_and_pos, color)

def list_count(l):
    #for python >= 2.7 you can use collections.Counter
    return dict((x, l.count(x)) for x in set(l))

def dict_max_value(d):
    return max(d.values())

def minmax(fun, actions):
    min, choice = None, None
    for action in actions:
        max = fun(action)
        if choice is None:
            min, choice = max, action
        elif max <= min:
            min, choice = max, action
    return choice

class Algo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.contenders = all_states()
    def initial_guess(self):
        return tuple([0] * (PEGS/2) + [1] * (PEGS - PEGS/2))
    def next_guess(self, qnas):
        self.filter_contenders(qnas[-1])
        #print "contenders size: ", len(self.contenders)
        return minmax(lambda (candidate):
            dict_max_value(list_count(
              [evaluate(contender, candidate) for contender in self.contenders]
            )), self.contenders)

    def filter_contenders(self, qna):
        self.contenders = [contender for contender in self.contenders
                                     if evaluate(contender, qna[0]) == qna[1]]

class Game():
    def __init__(self, algo):
        self.algo = algo
    def run(self):
        secret = random_secret()
        print "Secret:", secret
        qnas = []
        n = 1
        guess = self.algo.initial_guess()
        while True:
            answer = evaluate(secret, guess)
            qnas.append((guess, answer))
            print guess, "->", answer
            if answer == (PEGS, 0):
                break
            guess = self.algo.next_guess(qnas)
            n += 1
        print "Done in", n, "steps"

Game(Algo()).run()
```